# Convert time stored as hh24miss to hh24:mi:ss

Tags: oracle

I have a column in my table which will store the time as hh24miss format, i.e it stores as `091315` which is 09 hrs 13 min 15 sec. I need to convert it into HH24:MI:SS AND concatenate it with the date column which is in `YYYYMMDD` format.

Simply, the following columns Date: `19940601` and Time: `091315` need to be converted to
`01-Jan-94 09:13:15`.

Comment: Why are you storing the date and time in separate columns, and as strings? I take it both columns are `varchar2`?

Answer (score 3):

You should not store dates as strings, and there is no need to store the time in a separate field. [Oracle's `DATE` data type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020) includes times down the to the second. (You'd need `TIMESTAMP` for fractions of a second).

If you are really stuck with this schema then you need to convert the two strings into a `DATE`:

```
to_date(date_column || time_column, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

You can then display that in whatever format you want; what you showed would be:

```
to_char(to_date(date_column || time_column, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'),
  'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS')
```

Although the data you have is June, not January.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/542cd/1).

But really, please revisit your schema and use the appropriate data type for this, don't store the values as strings. You have no validation and no easy way to check that the values you have stored actually represent valid dates and times.

Comment: Thanks Alex.. Great work, you solved all my issues ;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @user2160918.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)